# What's wrong with my soup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am using python with BeautifulSoup 4 to find links in a html page that match a particular regular expression. I am able to find links and text matching with the regex but the both things combined together won't work. Here's my code:

```
import re
import bs4

s = '<a href="javascript://">Sign in&nbsp;<br /></a>'

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(s)

match = re.compile(r'sign\s?in', re.IGNORECASE)

print soup.find_all(text=match)  # [u'Sign in\xa0']
print soup.find_all(name='a')[0].text  # Sign in 

print soup.find_all('a', text=match) # []
```

*Comments are the outputs*. As you can see the combined search returns no result. This is strange.

Seems that there's something to do with the "br" tag (or a generic tag) contained inside the link text. If you delete it everything works as expected.

Comment: interestingly, the following works:  print soup.find_all('a')[0].find_all(text=match) It returns, [u'Sign in\xa0']

Answer (score 0):

you can either look for the tag **or** look for its text content but not together:

given that:

```
self.name = u'a'
self.text = SRE_Pattern: <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0xd52a58>
```

from the [source](https://github.com/kelp404/bs4/blob/master/element.py#L1541):

```
# If it's text, make sure the text matches.
elif isinstance(markup, NavigableString) or \
         isinstance(markup, basestring):
    if not self.name and not self.attrs and self._matches(markup, self.text):
        found = markup
```

that makes @Totem remark the way to go by design